# how to generate the dependency between files automatically?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, header-files

```
%.d: %.c
        @set -e; rm -f $@; \
        $(CC) -MM  $< > $@.$$$$; \
        sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
        rm -f $@.$$$$

sinclude $(SOURCES:.c=.d)
```

above is I saw at someone's blog, but it does not explain how the code work to create the dependency between .c and .h files in makefile.

is there someone who would explain it for me or supply some materials ?

I would really appreciate for your help!thank you!

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I have to say, that is just about the worst case of line noise I've ever seen outside of a sendmail.cf file. `$< > $@.$$$$; \`? Seriously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your only new source file is `foo.c`, which contains the lines

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"
```

Make determines that `foo.d` is out of date (because it doesn't exist or foo.c is newer), so it executes the rule.

```
%.d: %.c
        @set -e; rm -f $@; \
        $(CC) -MM  $< > $@.$$$$; \
        sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
        rm -f $@.$$$$

sinclude $(SOURCES:.c=.d)
```

Make evaluates the `$$$$` as `$$` and passes that to the shell; the shell interprets this as the value of the `$` parameter, which is the process ID of the shell, which the rule wants to use to construct a unique file name. This will remain constant *only within one command*, which is why the rule is written with the line continuations ("\"). This isn't really a good way to do it; if there are different processes trying to build `foo.d` at the same time, you're probably hosed anyway. So we can rewrite the rule:

```
%.d: %.c
        @set -e; rm -f $@
        $(CC) -MM  $< > $@.temp
        sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.temp > $@
        rm -f $@.temp

sinclude $(SOURCES:.c=.d)
```

We can dispense with the first rule, it doesn't really bear on the question.

The second command, `$(CC) -MM  $< > $@.temp`, expands to `gcc -MM  foo.c > foo.d.temp` (or some other compiler). The `-MM` flag tells the compiler to produce a list of dependencies:

```
foo.o: foo.c foo.h bar.h
```

The next line chews up this list with sed

```
sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g'
```

Which translates roughly as "change `foo.o:` to `foo.o foo.d :`":

```
foo.o foo.d : foo.c foo.h bar.h
```

(And the last command removes the temporary file.)

This is not the best way to handle dependencies, since it will rebuild all `%.d` files every time you run Make, even ones irrelevant to you target. A more polished approach is [Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation](http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html).

Answer (score 3):

[From gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/cpp/Invocation.html):

```
-M
Instead of outputting the result of preprocessing, output a rule suitable for make describing the dependencies of the main source file. ...

-MM
Like -M but do not mention header files that are found in system header directories, ...
```

So the command here:

```
$(CC) -MM  $< > $@.$$$$; \
        sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
```

Creates a temporary ($@.$$$$, i.e., target file name appended a unique number) file with `gcc -MM` output and using sed formats it so that when included by makefile the dependency file will look like `target file: [gcc generated dependencies]`. It then deletes the original `gcc -MM` output.

Answer (score 0):

The actual tracking of `#include`s is performed by the preprocessor (see [`-M` and `-MM` options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)).

> `-M`
>
> Instead of outputting the result of preprocessing, output a rule suitable for `make` describing the dependencies of the main source file. The preprocessor outputs one `make` rule containing the object file name for that source file, a colon, and the names of all the included files, including those coming from `-include` or `-imacros` command line options.
>
> `-MM`
>
> Like `-M` but do not mention header files that are found in system header directories, nor header files that are included, directly or indirectly, from such a header.

Also a pretty good overview of possible ways to track these type of dependencies is available [here](http://mad-scientist.net/make/autodep.html).

Answer (score 0):

For all the gobbledegook with the four dollar signs in a row, etc, the idea is fairly simple:

1. To create a file `xyz.d` from file `xyz.c`, run the commands shown...
2. The `$(CC)` line should probably include $(CFLAGS), but it assumes that the compiler is GCC (the `-MM` option is not standard elsewhere).  The `-MM` flag requests the compiler to generate output listing the headers (or other files) included in the source, so that you get the correct dependency information for the current platform.
3. The compiler compiles the source and writes the dependencies to standard output, which is redirected to a temporary file.  The expansion of `$@.$$$$` in the makefile is (for example), `xyz.$$` in the shell, where the `$$` becomes the PID of the shell running the script.
4. The `sed` command munges the output from the compiler so that a line starting `xyz.o` starts with <s>`xyz.o xyz` (so the object file and a program created from the object file both depend on the files after the colon)</s> `xyz.o xyz.d`, so both the object file and the dependency file need to be updated if any of the source or header files changes..
5. The output is written to `xyz.d`.
6. There is clean-up at top and bottom.
7. The `sinclude` line reads as many of the `.d` files as it can find.

[*Edited* to fix the discrepancy pointed out by [Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128940/beta).]

Comment: In 4), it changes `xyz.o` to `xyz.o xyz.d`, not to `xyz.o xyz`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler， i have a question: what's the difference between       "   sinclude ./header_dir/*.h  "and "  gcc -I ./Header_dir  "?

Comment: `sinclude ./Header_dir/*.h` is copying C code into the `makefile`, which is generally a bad idea (`make` doesn't understand C code, for all it knows how to compile it).  By contrast, `gcc -I./Header_dir` is making the headers in `Header_dir` available to the C compiler if the source contains `#include "someheader.h"` and there is a file `Header_dir/someheader.h`.  Completely different operations; one is bogus and the other sensible.  Note that the `sinclude` line is including the `xyz.d` dependency files.